# How to change stored JSON data when i clicked save button? swift 3

Tags: json, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I stored my user JSON data on "user" when I login. How can I change the value when i click save button?something like : crew_preferred_name to "Xiao Pang".

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "json")
user = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "json")as? NSDictionary
```

This is JSON Output

```
}
crew ={
"crew_avatar" = "http://ec2-52-221-231-3.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/gv/images/profile_image/Pang_Kang_Ming_916210_0e9.jpg";
"crew_contact" = 0123456789;
"crew_email" = "pang@xover.com.my";
"crew_gender" = Male;
"crew_id" = PP000001;
"crew_name" = "Pang Kang Ming";
"crew_preferred_name" = PKM;
"crew_qrcode" = "images/qrcode/qrcode_085960293a5378a64bec6ebfa3c89bb7.png";  }   

message = "Login Sucessfully";
result = success;
}
```

This is the button code, I'm posting the action to php but don't know how to change or save the changes in "user" data. Without the code i have to login again to see the new update.

```
@IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let preferName = preferNameEditLabel.text!;

    if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any], let crewID = crew["crew_id"] as? String, let crewEmail = crew["crew_email"] as? String, let crewContact = crew["crew_contact"] as? String {

        let param = ["action": "update profile", "crew": ["crew_id": crewID, "crew_preferred_name": preferName, "crew_email": crewEmail, "crew_contact": crewContact]] as [String : Any]

        let headers = [
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]

        if let postData = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])) {

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://52.221.231.3/gv/app_api.php")!,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData

            _ = URLSession.shared

            if preferNameEditLabel.text != ""{
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                    (data, response, error) -> Void in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.mutableContainers])) as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            let result = json["result"] as? String

                            if (result == "success") {
                                print(result!)

                                self.view.endEditing(true)

                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Updated", message: "Update Successfully", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
                                alert.addAction(okButton)
                                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                            }else{
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Update Failed", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
                                alert.addAction(okButton)
                                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                print(result!)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }

                task.resume()

            }else{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Empty!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okButton)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: simply save new value in UserDefaults against the same key.

Comment: @UmairAfzal This code?  UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "json")
user = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "json")as? NSDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply write this line after getting the latest data

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "json")
```

In this way your "json" key will contain latest data and you can get it as

```
user = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "json")as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: i tried this but the code removed all the data, maybe api.php doesn't respond the user data to us? any other solution for this case?

Comment: You can print your response to see what you are getting from server

Comment: I got result:"success" and message:"updated successfully". But not getting user data, so all the label display is empty. Is it need to change something at API.php? If can change on swift is better...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use its native Swift counterpart, `Dictionary`.

Then you can access and change a value associated with a known key like this (you will need to make sure that the type of `json` is `[String:Any]` before saving it to `UserDefaults` for this code to work):

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "json")
user = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "json") as! [String:Any]
user["crew_name] = "Pang Kang Feng"
```

Comment: sorry, i updated my question. how can i change the stored JSON data when i clicked the saved button?

Comment: Actually it's `user = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "json") as! [String:Any]`. Please don't adopt bad syntax like `value(forKey`